# Spring boot 1.5.1 REST returns null values by default

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I was using Spring Boot 1.4.4 and this version does not return null values from REST-controllers.

In 1.5.1 however, I get all values returned, even if they are null.

I looked at the changelogs but could not find any changes that would return null values.

Anyone got an idea?

Official changelogs:

- [Release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes)
- [Announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/30/spring-boot-1-5-1-released) of new version released

Comment: It did not happen to me though. Mind posting the related code?

Comment: See the answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been solved. It turns out that I was using a jackson property that was deprecated in 1.4, and that property was removed in 1.5.

Old property

```
# Old value
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion 
# should be replaced with
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion
```

Ref: [Spring Boot 1.4 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes)